# glPushMatrix() and glutSolidSphere() do not work together. Why?

Tags: opengl, glut

When I write the following code, everything works and an ellipsoid is displayed.

```
void HandModelCreator::drawModel(){
    palm();
}
void HandModelCreator::palm(){
    glColor4f(0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(1.0, 0.3, 0.45);
    glutSolidSphere (0.4, 20, 20);
}
```

I am trying to create a hierarchical model & need to use glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix(). So, I tried the following code, but nothing really worked. No ellipsoid was displayed. Why? What am I doing wrong?

```
void HandModelCreator::drawModel(){
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
        palm();
    glPopMatrix();
}
void HandModelCreator::palm(){
    glColor4f(0.6, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glScalef(1.0, 0.3, 0.45);
    glutSolidSphere (0.4, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: That's not OpenGL 3. That's something around 1.5; actually *all* the functions you are using are deprecated in 3.0 (well `glutSolidSphere` isn't actually OpenGL)

Comment: Yes. gluSolidSphere(...) is glut. So?
I chose 3 tags for this question "opengl", "opengl3" and "glut".
I don't know how to do the same thing in opengl3. It would be nice if you can help!

Comment: bah, it would be lengthy.

Comment: What would be lengthy? I don't mind doing it in OpenGL 1.5, however this code doesn't work! Why? The minute I write glLoadIdentity() it doesn't work!

Comment: because you push identity. You simply have no idea what that code is supposed to do.

Comment: Okay... So, can you explain in detail? I want to create a hand. I am very new to OpenGL!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32743/discussion-between-bartek-banachewicz-and-prerna-chikersal)

Comment: @PrernaChikersal: Before you create a hand you must understand how OpenGL works at all. Go to some fine tutorial, like the one at http://arcsynthesis.org/gltut work through it, then you can start doing your own thing.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling `glLoadIdentity()` before pushing the matrix on the stack? The idea of a stack is, that you push before you make the changes you later want to revert.

Furthermore, I don't think you want `glLoadIdentity()` there at all, because that resets the whole modelview matrix (i.e. whatever transformation hierachy you had, is then gone):

This is closer to what you actually need:

```
void HandModelCreator::drawModel(){
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
        palm();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: What really does glLoadIdentity(...) do?

Comment: *Replaces* the top of the current matrix stack with a 4x4 [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix).

Answer (score 1):

Before pushing the matrix, you set it to identity (using `glLoadIdentity`). This will of course cancel all previous transformations accumulated into the modelview matrix and might very well be the reason why you cannot see anything.

I advise you to delve a little deeper into how OpenGL's transformation pipeline and matrix transformations in general work.